# HTML autocomplete username causing password field to be filled in, once user already logged in

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, passwords

Very strange issue is occurring and has to do with my browsers capability to remember passwords. So I have a few login details and have rememberd them upon login. I move to the area of the site where I manage users. There is a field for their initials, and after that is a password field. If I double click in the initials input field I get a list of a all usernames that I login to the site with. If I select one it will autocomplete the below password field with the relevant stored password.

My Question is how can I disable this once logged in? I set the form and both inputs autocomplete attribute to off, still no success. I know it has to do with the fact that the browser (FireFox) see's a password field and "Assumes" the prior field is the username field. This is a extremely huge assumption. If I change the input type to text the autocompleteing does not work. So its all based on the fact that its a password field and the prior text input must be the username. The changing of the fields ids don't change anything

Below Is the form and fields:

```
<div class="row">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("UserCreate", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "UserCreateForm", autocomplete = "off" }))
                {
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Initial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-8 popovers" data-container="body" data-trigger="hover"
                             data-placement="top" data-content="Required">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Initial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Initial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/span-->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-8 popovers" data-container="body" data-trigger="hover"
                             data-placement="top" data-content="Required">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/span-->
                }
                </div>
```

Thanx for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found a workaround. Still not ideal but does the job

```
<input type="text" style="display:none">
<input type="password" style="display:none">
```

Pretty much fools the browser.